# Do ongoing parse.com requests continue to count against the API limit?

Tags: parse-platform

My understanding of the parse.com API rate limit is that it’s not a concurrent-job limit, it’s just the number of requests started in a given second. So if a user is, say, uploading a file from a slow network and it takes 30 seconds, that’s not 1 of my 30 req/s taken up that whole time. It’s just one request, the first second.

On my team, though, is a wonderful security guy whose job it is to worry. He thinks that if 30 users upload a file each, for 30 seconds, at a 30 r/s limit, no one else will be able to use our app until they are done.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your understanding was correct.  It's the number of requests started per second.  The duration of the request does not come in to play.

Source: I work at Parse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. I've made some experiments with Parse, for example i reloaded a `UITableview` 10 or 20 times in one second (can't remember) for 3-4 minutes and checked the requests in the admin panel. The maximum value was always less than 30, but it doesn't matter, the point is that you can test it this way and get more informations.

Just create some test project and reload the `SampleViewController.m` (which contains a Parse query) 30 times in one second, after this you can check the data browser which will display the traffic by req/sec.

As a second option you can upload a bunch of images by current user in every second, since the upload time is longer than 1 sec, you can check what happens when you start uploading a bunch of images (or other data) in every second.